# What is the slug of mainpage?

Tags: uri

I am editing blocks in /admin/structure/block - when I click "Configure" for a block, I see:

- Show block on specific pages
- All pages except those listed
- Only the listed pages
- Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)

I need to show the block only on the mainpage. How to do this? I don't know what is the slug for mainpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'mainpage' you mean the front page, the token is simply

```
<front>
```